# How can I change the filed email from Larval 8 auth user table to username?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-authentication

1. currently, I'm trying to change the field `email` in user table to `username`. But seems like it did not work at all. What I did just replace the `email` (inside of `$fillable` array) to `username`.

2.Here is the code for User.php file.

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'username',
        'password',
    ];
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
    
    /**
     * Get the identifier that will be stored in the subject claim of the JWT.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getJWTIdentifier() {
        return $this->getKey();
    }
    /**
     * Return a key value array, containing any custom claims to be added to the JWT.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getJWTCustomClaims() {
        return [];
    }

    public function username()
    {
        return 'username';
    }
}
```

Here is the schema for my user table
[image]

Comment: "_I'm trying to change the field email in user table to username_" There already is a field `username` in the `users` table.

Answer (score 1):

You also have to update your user table migration. If you don't need the email field, you can replace the line :

```
$table->string('email')->unique();
```

with  :

```
$table->string('username');
```

Then, run :

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

Answer (score -1):

For this situtation you need to update your migration file for this, then you can use your username without e-mail.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).